# Trope where Everyone Believes Something when they Should Know Better

Tags: trope

In the novel *Dune* we are told that doctors from the Suk school receive Imperial conditioning so that their loyalty is unbreakable, and no doctor from this school will ever act in a way that will harm their patients.

However, the bad guys are easily able to break the loyalty of the one and only Suk-trained doctor we meet in the series, by the tactic of holding his wife hostage; and this is related as if nobody had ever tried to break the loyalty of a Suk-trained doctor by holding his or her family hostage.

Is there a name for a trope in which the reader is assured of some categorical truth, but which "truth" is actually false in every instance observed in the narrative?

Comment: This question appears to be a) Entirely opinion-based and b) Not about scifi.

Comment: Is there any entity beside TVTropes that assigns names to tropes? On that website, that trope would probably fit into the "Informed ..." set of tropes.

Comment: We've had questions like this come up on the Literature SE, although [the last time](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/name-of-the-phenomenon-accepting-accusations-and-mold-of-character-into-the-acc/14805#14805), I gave the TV Tropes entry. :)

Comment: The work "unbreakable" directs us to Sci-Fi. Dune and trope are both accepted topics here. I am adamantly against the closure of this question.

Comment: In this case, there is a well-accepted name. I vote to reopen.

Comment: @Adamant - And while that may be true, just because a question is *answerable* doesn't make it *topical*. The concept of an unreliable narrator exists well outside scifi